# How do I keep a control at the bottom or right of a panel when the panel changes size?

Tags: delphi, layout, panel

There have been a few similar questions with solutions, but none answered my question, so here it is.

Making a `TPanel` collapse/expand with a `TButton` on it is ridiculously simple, or so I thought. I played around and by putting the button at the very top (for expansion/collapse of height from top to bottom) or left (for expansion/collapse of width from left to right) everything worked as planned. In fact all of the expandable/collapsible "advanced" panels work in the exact same way - the button is placed on top or left only. Soon enough I hit a wall: if you put the button at the bottom or right for expansion/collapse of height or width respectively, the buttons stay where they are on... the client area (?) - I lack the knowledge to explain this properly, but I'll presume that it is clear what is happening until otherwise pointed out. The point is that with the way I'm doing this the only solution would be to reposition the button within the panel, but that might put in on top of say some other components which should not be visible at all.

So the question is: how can I make this happen properly? as my idea of resizing the panel and then repositioning the button doesn't look like a proper approach to this problem. Alternatively, I'd gladly take some component that does this, however from the components that I have checked out, all act the same, even JEDI VCL `TJvRollOut` component can set `Placement` (of the button/caption) only to `plTop` or `plLeft`, so I'm thinking this isn't as simple to do?

Comment: Something like `AnimateWindow(Panel1.Handle, 250, AW_SLIDE or AW_HOR_POSITIVE or AW_HIDE);` ?

Comment: Is animation really so necessary? It can cause a lot of flickering

Comment: @TLama, truth be told, I have never used or seen `AnimateWindow`, I'll have to go and read up on it, unless you can explain here in a few words, or post an answer so I can try it out right now in my program

Comment: @hubalu, not really, I'd like the panel at least to appear magically at from the bottom, but now that i'm thinking about it, n order to do that, I will have to probably reposition the panel too... it can't expand up...

Comment: Is the button dedicated to trigger the collapsing/expansion located inside the panel ?

Comment: @Raith, the `AW_HIDE` in `AnimateWindow` will hide the panel, so it doesn't cover your needs. But anyway you might better to include a screenshot of what you want to do. I guess I know what you want, but still not 100% sure.

Comment: @TLama, this is the ideal behaviour that I would like http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/8794/expcollpan.jpg push button1 and panel1 expands like that, I was working from the other end, I had a panel1 expanded and then tried collapsing it, button1 "disappeared", but even with it starting out as collapsed expanding it just makes it go beyond the form1 client area, therefore there is need to reposition both the panel1 and the button1

Comment: Will anchoring the button to the bottom or left of the panel work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set to your button [`Anchors`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Anchors) property to `[akLeft, akBottom]`.

[image]

Comment: And now I know what `Anchors` do. Thank you very much. I knew where they were, however never needed them and so never looked into what they do. I'm so dumb, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties for adjusting the alignment of any tool in delphi:

1. Align (alNone, alLeft, alRight, alTop....)
2. Anchors (akLeft, akRight, akTop, akBottom)

e.g.
You have a panel and drag a TEdit on the TPanel. Now, you want TEdit to occupy ONLY top-left corner of TPanel and its distance form the bottom and right corners of the panel should remain constant irrespective of changing the panel size (which means TEdit expands if you extent panel along the bottom or right corners).

1. Set Align-> alNone. (not alLeft or else tEdit would occupy entire left region on panel and not just top-left).
2. Set Anchors-> akLeft=akTop=akRight=akBottom=True.
                In case you set akLeft=akTop=True and akRight=akBottom=False: then the size of TEdit remains constant on expanding panel along the bottom or right corners.